# getting "packet counter not numeric" when setting iptables dnslimit

Tags: iptables

I get this exact error:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 --set --name dnslimit
iptables v1.3.5: -c packet counter not numeric
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to provide packet and byte counts to the `--set` flag, which is being interpreted as an unambiguous match for `--set-counters`, aka `-c`.  From `man iptables`:

> -c, --set-counters packets bytes
>
> This enables the administrator to initialize the packet and byte counters of
>   a rule (during INSERT, APPEND, REPLACE operations).

My *guess* is that you're trying to use the `recent` module, in which case what you're really doing wrong is missing the `-m recent`.  But that's only a guess.

Comment: I've tried that, adding -m recent, it still errors

Comment: Don't tell us, **show us**; cut-and-paste (don't retype) the command and the response, into your question above.